# Access to the path is denied when uploading file to program files\some commercial program

Tags: c#, file

I get an error :

```
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MetaTrader FIX\experts\indicators\Awesome.ex4' is denied./n   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
   at Iron_loader.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Damian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Iron loader\Iron loader\Program.cs:line 55
```

when I run my exe file from \bin\Debug .
I don't know why is that. In destination directory there is no such file, so I think that there is a problem with security, ecause when I run my program from VS as admin everything goes ok.

I'm trying to upload files to folder of other program(not mine).
How can I copy that file?

```
File.Create(newPath);
File.Copy(pathOfFileFromMyDebugDirectory, newPath);
```

Comment: @IAbstract Maybe for not reading the exception message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...see **Edit** below

I believe that part of the problem is that the 'process' has not yet released the file handle. Try this:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Create(newPath))
{}

File.Copy(pathOfFileFromMyDebugDirectory, newPath);
```

As soon as you hit the closing brace in the using block, the base stream `Dispose()` method is called and all resources - including the process' file handle - should be released.

**Edit**
Are you getting the exception at the 'File.Create' call? I misread the error you gave. If you are getting the exception at the Create() method, then you need to make sure you have the **right** to **write** to the path.

I believe, that when you rectify the rights issue, you **may** get an exception that the handle is in use by another process. If so, use my suggestion above to fix.

Comment: I run my application as Administrator, and as you said, then I saw exception that the handle is use by another process and your fix works :)

Answer (score 2):

Check permissions on the folder. The user doesn't have modify / Full Control permissions.

Select property on the folder then select Security tab and check permissions for the current user or the user that your app. is running as.

Comment: The problem is I can't modify those permissions by clicking , because clients need to run this program themselves. So maybe I need to show User Control alert at start ?

Answer (score 2):

if the operating system and following WindowsXP, epoxy will not read and write in C: \ ProgramFilesx86, because the uac.

You must start your application with administrator privileges.

Regards.